# Sending response code to browser in PHP

Tags: php, header, response

I have follow PHP Code

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");

if(headers_sent()){
    echo "Header Sent";
}
else{
   echo "Header Not Sent";
}
?>
```

Still I am getting the message "Header Not Sent".

means response code is not sent. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before header use `ob_start();` and after `ob_end_flush();`

```
ob_start();
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
ob_end_flush();

if(headers_sent()){
    echo "Header Sent";
}
else{
   echo "Header Not Sent";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try flushing the output buffer

```
<?php
flush();
...
```